# AWS: Can't access 2nd NIC through EC2 dashboard

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm kind of fumbling through this, but I think I'm doing everything right.  I have two Network Interfaces on my instance (t2.micro). One has two Elastic IPs.  I'm trying to get a 3rd elastic IP on the 2nd interface going.  I have tried through the EC2 dashboard to associate this IP w/ the 2nd NIC, and and from EC2 -> Network Interfaces -> Manage IP Addresses.  Both times I get a permission error.  For the latter, it's

```
[interface name]: You do not have permission to access the specified resource.
```

That seems obvious enough, but I am logging in with the main account email and password -- not with IAM credentials.  Am I mistaken thinking that I had root access?  It even warns me on some screens that I'm not using IAM limited access.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that second card might have been the loopback device.  Feel free to chime in.  I was able to add another network device.  When I run ifconfig -a in a terminal I see more devices now.  I see no IPv4 addresses so I've done something bad, but that's another issue.